# The proper way to debug c# code with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a client-server application using C# with MySQL backend. I'm trying to figure out what objects are created that multiply the connection used for mysql. 
Root of the problem is not properly ended connections.

I'm looking for some way to check inside/outside of Visual Studio all objects that create connection.

From MySQL side I see all connections, and how many of them are from which client, but on client site i dont know which object/backgroundworker is doing the connection.

Comment: Search every instance of MySqlConnection objects and check that they are properly enclosed inside a using statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to by Steve's comment, wrap with a **using** block; this will close and dispose of the connection object as soon as it's out of scope.

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(...))
{
    using (IDbCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("select ...", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()';
        // process reader, etc
    }
}
```

*IDisposable* implementers should be inside a using.
*IDbConnection*s should not be global variables, they should be constructed, used and disposed in scope, or passed into methods as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

from what i read i think you want to make sure your application only opens 1 connection and make sure that connection is closed properly.

I am using a class to connect to the database which simply has a select method which opens and closes the connection, the beauty of this is you don't need singletons or need to worry about multiple threads since when ever the select method is executed the connection is closed automatically:

```
/// <summary>
/// class which controlls the database, 
/// </summary>
public class DBConnect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;

    /// <summary>
    /// the constructor which starts to initialize the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public DBConnect(string username, string password)
    {
        Initialize(username, password);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// initiates connection string for the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    private void Initialize(string username, string password)
    {
        string server = "Localhost";

        string database = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + username + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// opens the connection to the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can catch your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //1042: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 1042:
                    MessageBox.Show("MySqlException: cannot connect to the server");
                    break;

                //case 1045:
                //    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                //    break;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n" +
                ex.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ioe);
            MessageBox.Show("Er is al een connectie geopend");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// closes the connection with the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true or false depending on the succes of closing the connection</returns>
    private bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generally used to get multpile rows of data from the datbase
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">SQL statement</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DataTable Select(MySqlCommand cmd)
    {
        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            //Read the data and store it in a DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            try
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured loading the data: \n" + e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();

            //return list to be displayed
            return dt;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code:

```
public DataSet MySQL_Select(string query)
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection msqlConnection = null;
            msqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=" + MYSQL_SERVER + ";user id=" + MYSQL_login + ";Password=" + MYSQL_password + ";database=" + MYSQL_SCHEMAS + ";persist security info=False; Allow Zero Datetime=true ");
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            try
             {
                MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, msqlConnection);
                mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                msqlConnection.Close();
            }
            return (DS);
        }
```

Can I improve it ? to be sure I allways close connection, because from what i know finally statement do it proper.